# Angular 2 stateless or stateful?

Tags: angular, stateless, stateful

So here is my problem. I have this component here which edits a contact passed through the input. This code works and the contact parameters are changed when i change something in the input text ( two way databinding ) and then "saved" when a hit save and route to another component ( which displays a list of all contacts ).

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Contact} from "./contact";
import {Router} from "angular2/src/router/router";
import {OnInit} from "angular2/src/core/linker/interfaces";
import {ContactService} from "./contacts.service";

@Component({
    selector:'editor',
    template:`
    <div class='editor'>
        <label>Edit name : </label><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="contact.name">
        <br>
        <label>Edit email : </label><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="contact.email">
        <br>
        <label>Edit phone number: </label><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="contact.phone">
        <br>
        <div class="description">
        Description: 
        <br>
        <textarea rows="4" cols="50" [(ngModel)]="contact.description"></textarea>
        </div>
        <br>
        <input type="button" (click)="onCreateContact()" class="button" value="Save Changes"/>
    </div>
`,
    inputs:["contact"],
    styles:[
      `
        label {
          display: inline-block;
          width: 145px;
          border-left: 3px solid #006ec3;
          padding-left: 8px;
          padding-bottom: 8px;
        }
        .description{

          border-left: 3px solid #006ec3;
          padding-left: 8px;
          padding-bottom: 8px;
        }
      `
    ]
})

export class ContactEditorComponent implements OnInit{

    public contact:Contact;

    constructor(private router:Router){

    }

    onCreateContact(){
      this.router.navigate(['Contacts']);
    }

}
```

Now if i change my class this way by adding a `temp:Contact` variable which takes a clone of my contact , changing the temp variable then cloning it to the contact object , the changes are not saved anymore when i hit the button.

```
@Component({
    selector:'editor',
    template:`
    <div class='editor'>
        <label>Edit name : </label><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="temp.name">
        <br>
        <label>Edit email : </label><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="temp.email">
        <br>
        <label>Edit phone number: </label><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="temp.phone">
        <br>
        <div class="description">
        Description: 
        <br>
        <textarea rows="4" cols="50" [(ngModel)]="temp.description"></textarea>
        </div>
        <br>
        <input type="button" (click)="onCreateContact()" class="button" value="Save Changes"/>
    </div>
`,
    inputs:["contact"],
    styles:[
      `
        label {
          display: inline-block;
          width: 145px;
          border-left: 3px solid #006ec3;
          padding-left: 8px;
          padding-bottom: 8px;
        }
        .description{

          border-left: 3px solid #006ec3;
          padding-left: 8px;
          padding-bottom: 8px;
        }
      `
    ]
    }) 

export class ContactEditorComponent implements OnInit{

    public contact:Contact;
    public temp:Contact;
    constructor(private router:Router){

    }

    onCreateContact(){
      this.contact = (<any>Object).assign({}, this.temp);
      console.log(this.contact.name);
      this.router.navigate(['Contacts']);
    }

  ngOnInit(){
      this.temp = (<any>Object).assign({}, this.contact);
  }
}
```

All my contacts are saved in another file containing a Const array of contacts and accessed through a contact.service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That has nothing to do with Angular, and everything to do with JavaScript.

Here's an example:

```
const parent = {};
parent.contact = {id: 'c1'};
const child = {};
child.contact = parent.contact;
```

Now both `child.contact` and `parent.contact` are references to the same object. So

```
child.contact.id = 'c2';
console.log(parent.contact.id);
```

will print 'c2'.

That's what you're doing in your first example.

Now your second example does:

```
const parent = {};
parent.contact = {id: 'c1'};
const child = {};
child.contact = parent.contact;
child.temp = {id: 'c1'}; // clone of child.contact
```

So now, `child.temp` references a new object, that is different (a copy) from `child.contact` and `parent.contact`.

Then you're modifying the id of the `temp` contact:

```
child.temp.id = 'c2';
```

Then, when saving, you're doing

```
child.contact = {id: 'c2'}; // clone of child.temp
```

So now you have 3 different objects: one that is references by `parent.contact`, and which still has 'c1' as id, `child.temp` which is a modified copy of `parent.contact`, and child.contact which is yet another copy of `child.temp`.

If you want to change the value of the id of the object referenced by `child.contact` and `parent.contact`, you need, instead to do

```
child.contact.id = temp.contact.id;
```

or, in your example:

```
Object.assign(child.contact, temp.contact);
```

Comment: That worked like a charm thanks! so in order to create on the same object we use :
     Object.assign(contact, contact);
and not 
     child.contact = Object.assign({},contact);
which only creates a new copy of the object. Did i get that right ?

Comment: Object.assign copies all the direct properties of the second object to the first one, and returns the first one. So if you use Object.assign({}, conact), you create a new empty object, and then copy all the properties of contact to this new empty object. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign